# glassfish JDBC Connection Pooling and oracle global temporary table same sessionId

Tags: oracle, glassfish, database-connection, connection-pooling, temp-tables

Before I start with my question, I would like to clarify that I am java/j2ee developer and have limited understanding of things on oracle side.

I am using glassfish server with JDBC connection Pooling and in back side, oracle database.
Also i am using global temporary table of oracle to execute some work flow.

i am storing session specific data in global temp table.

Now my issue is most of the time i am getting the same sessionId for each connection.

Does that means i can't use glboal temporary table with glassfish JDBC connection Pooling.

Another interesting thing is if i removed connection pooling then i am getting different sessionID for each connection.

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Connection Pooling it's always best to not leave states in the database session when the connection is released into the pool. That's because there is no guarantee that you'll get back the same connection the next time you need one. A global temp table (GTT) is an example of such a state and belongs to one Database session, or to one JDBC connection (there is a 1-1 mapping between DB session and JDBC connection). It won't be visible if you use another JDBC connection.
So if your business logic requires that you use a GTT then you should not release the connection back to the pool until you're dong using this GTT. Note that this goes against the best practices which recommend to release the connection back to the pool as soon as possible. As an alternative you may use a normal table and commit your temporary results into it so that they can be accessed through any other connection.